# Remove specific shared links in Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

How do I remove a specific link in the shared links list? I have some links in there that I do not want to keep since it's taking up a lot of space and it makes me hard to search for the links I actually care about.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the Subscriptions link at the bottom, you can see all the feeds you have added and can choose to remove the ones you no longer want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the list of sharing options presented at the bottom of the page when you tap the Share button?

Have you scrolled all the way to the right side of those icons and tapped the button with 3 dots with `More` underneath?

That will allow you to turn share sheets off, on, an rearrange them in the list.

Comment: Sorry, I added a screenshot to clarify what I meant.